# Getting error while creating jar using maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to create a jar, that contains some test classes and a main class that runs those test classes using custom junit runner. I have used maven assembly plugin. The jar is getting created but when I try to run the jar using

```
java -jar <nameofthejar>
```

it gives error saying:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ora.arb.tap.Main
```

Here is my project structure:

```
src:
- main:
  - java:
  - resources:
- test:
  - java:
    - tap:
      - Main
      - TestClass1
      - TestClass2
  - resources:
```

assembly plugin from pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.ora.arb.tap.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/tap</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Whats the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you check if you have class `Main` in package `com.cisco.webex.tap`

Comment: Is your `Main` class really in `src/test/java/...`? If so this will not work because the `src/test` area will never being packaged. You have to move your main class to `src/main/java/<package>` location instead. Furthermore why are you using such an older version of [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Comment: yeah I can update the maven assembly package, but is there no way I can package a main class under test package?

Comment: and then if I move Main class under src/main/java, it will be unable to access Test Classes under src/test/java.

Comment: Why would you like to package test class into a jar file? Test classes are executed as test during `mvn test` or maybe you have integration tests executed by maven-failsafe-plugin named like `*IT.java` ... so I don't understand your approach to package into a jar (apart from using maven-assembly-plugin).. ?

Comment: Can you give more details about `custom junit runner`? JUnit or JUnit Jupiter?

Comment: I want to have a separate jar containing some of the tests, so that they can be ran as a verifier against the main code.
Its JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing Same issue,

please check if you have added packaging jar at top your pom.xml inside  tag.

like this:

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.rohan</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmetertester</artifactId>
    **<packaging>jar</packaging>**
```