# Jar created using maven-assembly-plugin not running with mvn install

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am creating a jar file using maven assembly plugin.
The minimal pom file looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.org.taptest.tests.TestsRunningAsTAP</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run `mvn clean install`, it creates a jar file but when I run the jar file using `java -jar <jarfileName>`, it says `Error: Could not find or load main class`.
While if I edit the above pom, to have

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                          
       <mainClass>com.org.taptest.tests.TestsRunningAsTAP</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and after running `mvn clean install`, I run `mvn compile test-compile assembly-plugin`, it generates the same jar file, but this jar file runs as expected.
So, my question is why the jar file with the first approach does not runs and what exactly does `mvn compile test-compile assembly-plugin` command do?

Comment: My assumption is first: This class `TestsRunningAsTAP` is a test? Second only use `mvn clean package` nothing else...

Comment: Its a main class that runs the tests.
yeah I am using ```mvn clean install```, but then too the jar getting generated from this, does not runs

Comment: Tests should be run by using the default life cycle `test` and done by surefire or failsafe in case of integration tests. But using to create an executable via assembly-plugin nor does that work because the resulting jar-with-dependencies is lacking the test dependencies which. are never being packaged by default.

Comment: But it works when I create the jar using ```mvn compile test-compile assembly:single```. Why the executable jar created using this command runs?

Comment: You are repeating several steps which is not necessary and the test could be executed in one go via `mvn clean test` ... that's simpler and you will follow convention over configuration...

Comment: Though its a test code, but its not under src/test scope, as I wanted to create an executable jar for some of my tests file, I put it under src/main scope. Now when I am using ```mvn clean install```, it generates 2 jar one my main project jar and the other test jar but while running the test jar it says ```Error: Could not find or load main class```
But as I mentioned in the question, if I use the command explicitly ```mvn compile assembly:plugin```, then I am able to run this test jar as desired.

Comment: Why not under `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources`... Testfiles belong to `src/test/resources` ... creating a test jar form main does not make sense (follow the conventions)...can you explain why are you doing this? What kind of problem you are trying to solve? Please describe that problem...not the problem you have while violating the conventions etc. Best would be an example project on Gitbub or alike to have something concrete...

Comment: I am using maven assembly plugin to create an executable jar. If I keep my test code under src/test and package the jar, it creates the jar but the jar execution fails with ```Error: Could not find or load main class.```
So I have to move the code under src/main. Please follow the link for details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151197/getting-error-while-creating-jar-using-maven-assembly-plugin
By the way, thats a separate discussion, we are getting away from the question, lets get back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing Same issue,

please check if you have added jar at top you pom.xml inside  tag.

like this:

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.rohan</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmetertester</artifactId>
    **<packaging>jar</packaging>**
```